# Access SVN repository through dynamic ip

Tags: svn

We have a lan network in our office and had created a svn repository on one of the computer and we access that repository through the url svn://10.0.0.5 where 1.0.0.5 is the ip address of that computer. Now i want to access this repository through internet. So what will be my url as we get dynamic ip address through isp. And all computers are behind routers so how to access this

Comment: You'll need to publish the server through your firewall. What firewall / router are you using? Also I'm not 100% sure there's any encryption of passwords etc. on plain svn:// URLs so you might want to use ssh+svn remotely, so publish a locked-down ssh instead.

Comment: I suggest moving this question to superuser.com - but I can tell you that you've got a large work in front of you - and much knowledge to gain.

Comment: can you use the PC name?

Comment: A VPN might be another option that could work for you.

Comment: @Rup we are using netgear router

Comment: @shawn we cant use computer name

Comment: @Russ makes a good point - who's going to access this? Your own users remotely, a third-party who don't have permissions to your network, or the public in general?

Comment: @jimy: is requesting a static IP from your ISP out of the question?  Seems obvious, but most offer it as a feature now.

Comment: There's many different types of netgear routers (and I don't know any of them). Do you have any port-publishing features in the router's admin website? You might also have to check that your ISP won't filter out your server traffic!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

poke the server through the firewall as others have suggested, then use a service such as dyndns to update a dns record with your dynamic ip address as it changes. Then you can always reference the machine from the dns entry.

So, you set up svn.yourcompanyname.org with dyndns, you install their app on your svn server, so it updates dyndns with it's current external ip address, and then you always reference your svn repository by connecting to svn.yourcompanyname.org

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that you can't.

Longer answer is, to reliably access your repository you'd first need a static IP address from your provider.  After you have the static IP you'd then need to configure your router and firewall to forward traffic to that IP that is destined for the port you have set up SVN on to forward to your SVN server.

Comment: Dyndns exists. A static IP is not needed for that. Only your description on the firewall/port forwarding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need some form of stable name. [DynDNS](http://dyndns.com) or one of the many others providing dynamic DNS would suffice. Still, Rup is of course right: You can't use 10.0.0.5 from outside your office network, since it is a non-routable address. Your firewall needs to get port forwarding and then you need to point clients at the firewall.

Just note the obvious security problems with opening holes in your firewall, mke sure the svn server is in the DMZ (and if you don't currently have one, quite seriously, either drop the idea or get the network admin to create one – if they really consider port forwarding into your regular network office, get a new network admin).

Now, if all you really want to achieve is to give your own developers access from home or from their laptops, then VPN is what you should do.